# After updating to 13.6.5, in addition to a totally empty Login Items screen in Settings-General, I could no longer sign in to MS OneDrive

Tags: login, ventura, onedrive

After updating to Mac OS Ventura 13.6.5,I could also no longer sign in to my Microsoft OneDrive and Google Drive apps as both would hang when I launch them. The local folder of OneDrive is also gone. I am able to launch other Microsoft apps though. I can also launch both drive apps online, i.e. from my web browser (Safari). I have not checked similar apps yet so I'm unaware if there are issues with them as well.

In addition, the Login Items in Settings-General is now empty and I could no longer add any new items to it.

Has anyone encountered the same problems? Great chance this is a Mac OS issue as I was able to run OneDrive, and was able to add a new login item in Settings which showed up together with the previous ones, just right before the update.

Has anyone encountered the same problems and by chance found a solution?